# How to implement nested tables dynamically in tabulator

Tags: javascript, typescript, callback, tabulator

I'm attempting to implemented nested tables in tabulator where the data could be nested to n-levels.
The issue that I'm having is that the function assigned to `rowFormatter` is not able to see the `createTable()` method. How do I allow the callback function to see the `createTable()` function, or other functions in my class?

```
 private createTable(element: HTMLDivElement,jsonFileContents, schemaId: string): Tabulator {
    var table = new Tabulator(this.tab, {
      columns: this.buildHeaders(jsonFileContents, schemaId),
      data: this.buildRows(jsonFileContents, jsonFileContents.schema.find(s => s.parent == null).guid),
      rowFormatter:function(row) {
        var childrenSchemas = jsonFileContents.schemas.filter(s => s.parent == row["schemaId"]);
        if(childrenSchemas){
          childrenSchemas.forEach(schema => {
            var holderEl = document.createElement("div");
            var tableEl = document.createElement("div");
            holderEl.appendChild(tableEl);
            row.getElement().appendChild(holderEl);
            var subTable = this.createTable(tableEl, jsonFileContents, schema.guid); //<---HERE
          });
        }
      }      
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is because in the context of the `rowFormatter` `this` is referring to the Tabulator table object.

So you could either use an arrow function when defining the row formatter callback, which would preserve the scope of the parent:

```js
rowFormatter:(row) => {

}
```

or you could store the scope of `this` in a different variable, lets call it `self` and then use that in the callback:

```js
private createTable(element: HTMLDivElement,jsonFileContents, schemaId: string): Tabulator {
    var self = this;

    var table = new Tabulator(this.tab, {
        rowFormatter:function(row) {
            self.createTable();
        }
    });
}
```